# Alternate two colors in a column chart with independence of values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column/bar chart and I'd want to color it red and grey this way: first column red, second grey, third red, fourth grey and so on until there's no more values. I'm struggling with the macro recorder because it specifies every point but the idea is that data will be updated and will change the number of points/values to less or more depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a code that loops through the number of series/points in your chart. The code below loops through each series and/or points in a **selected** chart and formats every second bar with the same fill color.

```
Sub ColorBarsInChart()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'Exit if no chart is selected
    If Not (TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Or TypeName(Selection) = "PlotArea") Then Exit Sub

    'If only one series in chart
    If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 1 Then
        For j = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
            If j Mod 2 Then
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(127, 127, 127)
            End If
        Next j

    'If more than one series in chart
    Else
        For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
            For j = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Count
                If i Mod 2 Then
                    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Else
                    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(127, 127, 127)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Since I don't know if your specific chart consists of multiple data series, I have made the code versatile enough to work in both cases.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get it to work. Maybe something is missing? I'm in Excel 2013

Comment: How is it not working? Is it not formatting the correct bars or does it return an error?

Comment: Macro runs without problem but it doesn't color any column in an example column chart I tried.

Comment: Have you selected the chart? The macro exits if the chart is not selected, because of the line `If TypeName(Selection) <> ChartArea Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: Yep, I'm selecting the chart before running it.

Comment: Try to remove the line that I am talking about and run the macro.

Comment: Great, works like heaven. So it was that line that for some reason even sentencing the chart forced it to exit. Thanks a lot, I'll study this macro :)

Comment: Yeah. I made an error in that line. I have updated the code and you should be able to include that line of code again in order to avoid an error if you run the code without having selected a chart.